# Sass @use - import multiple times the same file

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have Reactjs project, using sass. I updated my Sass version from using node-sass to  "sass": "^1.38.0" (dart-sass).
I just change all my imports in scss files from using @Import to use @Use rule:

from:

```
@import "./src/general.scss";
```

to:

```
@use "src/general" as *;
```

I use this line of css in multiple Scss files, across the whole project.

Still, I see my "body" attribute from "_global.scss" file [loaded tones of times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhnO2.png), and it makes my debugging mode to be very slow, because each element I try to look at in the devtools, it take long time.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you `import`ing the SCSS file from multiple JavaScript files?

Comment: yes, but using use rule, not import

Comment: I get that you use using `@use` from SCSS files, but importing from JS files, do you import SCSS files multiple times throughout your app?

Comment: This should get a big highlight.